# C# - Customize column sorting of DataTable-bound DataGridView by the cells' background color

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, datagridview

I have a DataGridView component that is bound to a DataTable like so :

```
DgvResults.DataSource = ResultsData;
```

Said DataTable is created dynamically by converting a Dictionary which is itself obtained from comparing 2 excel files together and storing the comparison results (I think this portion of the code is not really relevant here but I can certainly show it if needed).

My DataGridView's Sorted event and the end of the above comparison process are bound to a method I have created which loops through all the rows and cells and assigns a certain background color to each cell based on certain criteria, again not really relevant to the question.

My question is : Knowing that bound DataGridView components cannot use the SortCompare event, is there a way for a click on a column header in the DataGridView to result in the results being sorted by background color?  I assume some kind of custom sorting mechanism using a custom comparer which has access to the DataGridView as well as the index of the column clicked will be needed but I cannot seem to find how to wire all this together.

I can provide more code if needed but the bulk of the issue resides in how to provide a custom sorting behavior for a DataTable that can be triggered by sorting a column on the associated DataGridView.

Comment: There is a `SortCompare` event which might work (hard to tell with so little to go on).  *a method I have created which loops through all the rows and cells* that is almost certainly not needed and highly inefficient.  Typically, you use the `RowPrePaint` event (or maybe `CellFormatting`) to efficiently color rows or cells.  **But**, if you have two things keyed off 'certain criteria' (color and now sort) you'd be better off creating a hidden column with a status code so it can be done just once.

Comment: The column index of the DGV is the same as DataTable so once you now the column use DataTable sorted = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>(index)).CopyToDataTable();